# Compare data after sequelize asynchronous query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code :

```
VerificationKey.getCode = async (visitorData, visitorCode, res) => {
  console.log("Verif model visitorCode" + visitorCode);

  const data = visitorData;
  const testCode = visitorCode;
  const findVisitor = await VerificationKey.findOne({ where: { data } })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then(() => {
      if (testCode == findVisitor.key) {
        res.status(200).json({ response: true });
      }
    });
};
```

What I need is to compare testCode and findVisitor.key values.
If they are equal, I want to return a boolean to the front end.

But I can't write it like this because it is not possible to access findVisitor.key before initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to change your code to use async/await syntax only - without `then` and `catch`:

```js
VerificationKey.getCode = async (visitorData, visitorCode, res) => {
  console.log("Verif model visitorCode" + visitorCode);

  const data = visitorData;
  const testCode = visitorCode;

  try {
    const findVisitor = await VerificationKey.findOne({ where: { data } });
    
    if(!findVisitor) {
      res.status(404).json({ response: false });
    } else if(testCode == findVisitor.key) {
      res.status(200).json({ response: true });
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ response: false });
    }
   } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
};
```

Comment: when I do that I get :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

Comment: So the problem is with `res`. Make shure that you give it corectly when calling `VerificationKey.getCode()`

Comment: Right, I forgot to pass the res parameter in the controller.
Thanks for your help